# How do I properly set my PATH variable in my .bash_profile? to use adb on Lion?

Tags: android, macos, osx-lion, adb

I am trying to get adb (Android Debugging Bridge) working on my MBP (OS X 10.7.3) and so far am having trouble. I know this is something simple....

I currently have my path set to:

```
PATH="$PATH:/Users/stevieo/android-sdk-macosx/tools;/Users/stevieo/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools"
export PATH
```

But when I source my .bash_profile, I still cannot launch adb, as I get: "-bash: adb: command not found"

Any and all thoughts and comments are appreciated!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon instead of colon between the two folder paths..

Answer (score 0):

Manfred,

You are correct sir! But, in addition, I also found that the platform-tools directory is located in /Users/stevieo/android-sdks/platform-tools, which was a different directory than I was originally pointing to.... Windows...Mac...Unix. Sometimes they all blend together....

Thanks all,

Steve O'Sullivan